# Comparing two tab delimited files and print matched rows

Tags: regex

I have two big tabular files, file1 and file 2. I want to compare these two files and print matched rows as showed below.

file_1

> ENSDARG00000000760
>   **ENSDARG00000001015**
>   ENSDARG00000001549
>   ENSDARG00000002445
>   ENSDARG00000003102
>   ENSDARG00000004594
>   ENSDARG00000004851

file_2

> ENSDARG00000000151  ENSDART00000000160    2292    chovy.60083
>   ENSDARG00000000151    ENSDART00000151127  1470    chovy.60083
>   ENSDARG00000000175    ENSDART00000146636  1832    chovy.300567
>   ENSDARG00000000966    ENSDART00000001092  6325    chovy.254634
>   ENSDARG00000000966    ENSDART00000140618  6295    chovy.254634
>   **ENSDARG00000001015  ENSDART00000001148  1791    chovy.388956
>   ENSDARG00000001015    ENSDART00000104891  1835    chovy.388956
>   ENSDARG00000001015    ENSDART00000141913  994     chovy.283553**

my desired output:

> ENSDARG00000001015 ENSDART00000001148  1791    chovy.388956
>   ENSDARG00000001015 ENSDART00000104891  1835    chovy.388956
>   ENSDARG00000001015 ENSDART00000141913  994     chovy.283553

my code:

> grep -wFf file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt

I think it is not working..

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: It is more a job for awk.

Comment: this should go to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ , no?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal: not really there are a lot of questions like this in SO (and tags like: `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, `bash`... that are programming languages themself (except for `grep` that is more a command)).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=1;next}a[$1]' file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
```

details:

`FNR==NR` is a condition that tests if the line number of the current file is equal to the current line number processed by awk (it's a trick to know if you are in the first file or in the second). When awk starts a new file `FNR` (File Number Row) is reset, but `NR` (Number Row) continues to be incremented line after line.

`{a[$1]=1;next}` if it is true, set the item of the array "a" with the field as key and 1 as value and go immediately to the next line.

`a[$1]` is a test too. if the first field of file2 is an existing key  in the array "a" (understand `a[$1]` is not null), the line is printed.